# rtrim(): Invalid '..'-range, '..'-range needs to be incrementing

Tags: php, laravel

Intento cambiar parte de unas URL de diversas entradas de post, logro hacerlo en la entradas que no presentan muchas complicaciones en las url de las imagenes, sin embargo las que poseen rutas variadas con espacios intercalados o dobles puntos me arrojan error.

Como las consulto desde una base de datos, hago el test con la que tiene la id que me genera el error del asunto de este post.

Le anexo el codigo de prueba que utilizo para cambiar partes de las URL de las imagenes.

```
$data= User::find(2);

  $html = $data->name;
$html = "<body>$html</body>";


$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NONET | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
if (is_null($dom)) {
} else {
  $a_nodelist = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

  foreach ($a_nodelist as $enlace) {
    $img = $enlace->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
    if ($img) {
      $urlImagen = $img->getAttribute('src');
      $imagenArreglo = explode("/", $urlImagen);
      $nombreImagen = end($imagenArreglo);




      $rutasinImagen = rtrim($urlImagen, $nombreImagen);

      dd($rutasinImagen);

      $nuevaruta = 'http://www.rumberos.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/imagen/';
      $file = fopen("archivo.txt", "a");
      fwrite($file, $data->id . PHP_EOL);
      fclose($file);

      DB::table("users")
        ->where("id", "=", $data->id)
        ->update(["name" => DB::raw("REPLACE(name,  '$rutasinImagen', '$nuevaruta')")]);
    }
```

Los post poseen codigo HTML asi que para obtener las url utilizo dom. Me sirve para algunas publicaciones, pero presiento que va a fallar para las que poseen url desordenadas. Por ejemplo la entrada que falla con el error anexado posee el siguiente contenido.

```
http://midominio.com/images/2014/HTV- Premios Heat - Juanes..jpg
```

hago el DD cuando separo el string para obtener el nomnbre de la imagen, y funciona bien hasta ahi, pero cuando intento borrar esa parte de la URL me arroja el error. Creo que debe ser porque posee los dobles puntos y espacios.

Saluydos

Comment: Al final lo resolvi tratando al texto, tuve que utilizar la funcion para remplazar texto en string, cambiando el doble punto que posee, no es una solucion factible debido al gran casos de variables que tendre, son mas del 40 mil registros, pero con el log que genero podre ir depurando poco a poco.

Comment: Ahora tengo otro problema, cuando la url posee muchos puntos me retorna el mismo error.